# Asking about PWA Capability to be accessed from chrome://apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, progressive-web-apps

### Asking about PWA Capability to be accessed from chrome://apps

I have noticed that some PWA websites can be installed using the menu bar like the following image. & these apps show directly in the chrome://apps
my PWAs don't show that option. Why ???

#### P.S: I passed all the normal PWA criterias & user engagement checks in lighthouse...

some example websites that explain this feature are:

- https://trivago.com/
- https://notepad.js.org/

[image]

Comment: @wOxxOm I know that... what I meant is the option in the image. How can I show (open in app) from the chrome menu. & show my app into the Chrome://apps

Comment: @AhmedBadawy There are several reasons Chrome might think an app is not installable. Please give an example.

Comment: @wOxxOm Chrome shows PWA's in chrome://apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me, it was missing the viewport... 
it's solved now. 
here's my header now:-

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="test app">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>PWA Testing</title>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="48x48" href="images/favicon-48x48.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="96x96" href="images/icon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="512x512" href="images/icon-512x512.png">

<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/icon-144x144.png">

<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="images/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#840012">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#410101">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#410101">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="browserconfig.xml" />

<meta name="application-name" content="PWA Testing Project">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="PWA Testing Project">

<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

<meta property="og:title" content="test app">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://airhorner.com/images/touch/Airhorner_192.png">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/">
<meta property="og:description" content="test app">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://example.com/">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Air Horn">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="test app">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://example.com/images/touch/Airhorner_192.png">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@ahmed_badawy_x">
```